# Can I drywall over a skylight without removing it?

Tags: drywall, skylight

Is it possible to put a **ceiling** over an existing skylight **without removing** the skylight? It's not leaking. We just want to divide the room in the middle of the skylight. Would it pose problems with heat building up inside the shaft?

Comment: It's not leaking *now*, but what about when it starts leaking next year?

Comment: That's what we plan to do currently. Actually just up to the ceiling outside the skylight opening. but I wondered if covering it will be a problem.

Comment: Opinion, but 20 years a carpenter: the skylight will eventually leak and damage your expensive finishes. Either remove the skylight properly or as @JACK said, leave it open.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your honest answer. I don't want to cause more problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the wall up into the skylite cavity but still keep it open and light both rooms...

Comment: IIRC, that was the exact situation we had in the row house I grew up in.  One skylight centered (roughly) above the wall dividing the 2 center rooms on the top floor.  This allowed them both to get some natural light.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as you plan on removing the skylight the next time you have work on your roof and you are OK with that particular area having a chance at water damage.   It isn't a big deal because if your skylight leaks now, its going to ruin something.

If you are selling the house anytime soon it will be a huge huge red flag having a hidden skylight.

There are no code issues with what you are doing, it is just weird.   Normally you do this after you take skylight out.   But I also get why you wouldn't have a non-leaking roof repaired.

Comment: We aren't repairing the roof at this time. However, if we ever have storm damage we will remove the skylight and close in the cutout. The bathroom is really hot with the skylight. It's huge, so it would be easier to cool in the summer without the skylight.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar where we added a wall and used light tubes below in each area but the skylight was enclosed with no problems, the light tubes provided much of the light the sky light did prior to the remodel.